# VersionConflict: (pip 9.0.2 (/usr/local/lib/python3.5/site-packages), Requirement.parse('pip==9.0.1')

Tags: python, docker, pip

I use docker commend `docker-compose build` and `docker-compose up -d`

`yum install python-35 -y` and install packages and I add `pip-3.5 install --upgrade pip` in docker-compose.yml it raise VersionConflict error

```
You are using pip version 9.0.2, however version 9.0.3 is available.
You should consider upgrading via the 'pip install --upgrade pip' command.
+ pip-3.5 install awscli
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 666, in _build_master
ws.require(__requires__)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 984, in require
needed = self.resolve(parse_requirements(requirements))
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 875, in resolve
raise VersionConflict(dist, req).with_context(dependent_req)
pkg_resources.VersionConflict: (pip 9.0.2 (/usr/local/lib/python3.5/site-packages), Requirement.parse('pip==9.0.1'))

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:
```

but i don't know why it requires pip==9.0.1 to me...

how can i solved problem using pip>=9.0.2?

**ADD**

My setup.py

```
install_requires = [
    'nitro>=1.3.0,<1.4.0',
    'mysqlclient',
    'requests',
    'beautifulsoup4',
    'google-api-python-client',
    'httplib2',
    'raven',
]
```

and when I check [aws-cli/setup.py](https://github.com/aws/aws-cli/blob/develop/setup.py) on github

and [aws-cli/requirement.txt](https://github.com/aws/aws-cli/blob/develop/requirements.txt)

there is no `pip=9.0.1`

and when i change `pip-3.5 install awscli` -> `pip-3.5 install ipython`

it have same error

```
+ pip-3.5 install ipython
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 666, in _build_master
ws.require(__requires__)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 984, in require
needed = self.resolve(parse_requirements(requirements))
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 875, in resolve
raise VersionConflict(dist, req).with_context(dependent_req)
pkg_resources.VersionConflict: (pip 9.0.3 (/usr/local/lib/python3.5/site-packages), Requirement.parse('pip==9.0.1'))

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/bin/pip-3.5", line 6, in <module>
from pkg_resources import load_entry_point
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 3144, in <module>
@_call_aside
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 3128, in _call_aside
f(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 3157, in _initialize_master_working_set
working_set = WorkingSet._build_master()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 668, in _build_master
return cls._build_from_requirements(__requires__)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 681, in _build_from_requirements
dists = ws.resolve(reqs, Environment())
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 870, in resolve
raise DistributionNotFound(req, requirers)
pkg_resources.DistributionNotFound: The 'pip==9.0.1' distribution was not found and is required by the application
```

Comment: Please paste content of `docker-compose.yml` if it's possible. Also you should add `docker` tag to this question to reach docker specialists.

Comment: Anyway I believe it's `awscli` wich has strict requirement on pip version 9.0.1. If it's possible take a look into requirements.txt of `awscli` and check if there is a foloowing line there `pip=9.0.1`. If so modify it to require `pip >= 9.0.1`.

Comment: @running.t Hi, i add seyup.py and awscli github url :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I solved my problem

`pip-3.5 install --upgrade pip`

and

`pip install awscli` not `pip-3.5 install awscli`

it is work fine

Answer (score 5):

Calling pip through python did the trick for me, e.g.:

```
python3 -m pip install --upgrade pip==9.0.1
```

(or whatever version you see in `Requirement.parse('pip==X.Y.Z')`)

Answer (score 0):

On Mac M1, it can be solved by reinstalling python by running `brew reinstall python`.